# docker-compose up postgresql error, chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data’: Operation not permitted

Tags: docker, docker-compose, postgresql-9.5

I'm working in a project and we use docker. The project was fine until last friday and today I started my computer (mac mini - macOS Sierra version 10.12.5 (16F73)) with an error.
I'm trying to run `docker-compose -f dev.yml -f docker-compose.yml up`, but when I execute this it returns the following message :

`db_1        | chmod: changing permissions of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data’: Operation not permitted`.

I had deleted all the docker containers and images `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` `docker rmi $(docker images -q)`but the error persists.

My docker-compose.yml is this:

```
 version: '2'

 services:

 rabbitmq:
     restart: always
     image: rabbitmq:3.6
     environment:
       RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: my_user
       RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: my_password
     ports:
       - "5672:5672"
       - "15672:15672"
   django:
     build: ./django
     command: gunicorn contactto.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8000
     environment: 
       - "TZ=Brazil/East"
     restart: always
     volumes: 
       - ./django:/usr/src/app
       - ./django/static:/usr/src/app/contactto/static
       - ./logs:/logs/
       - /asterisk/:/etc/asterisk/
     ports:
       - "8000:8000"
     links:
       - rabbitmq:rabbitmq
   node:
     build: ./node_6_8
     environment:
       - "TZ=Brazil/East"
     volumes_from:
       - django
   nginx:
     build: ./nginx
     restart: always
     environment: 
       - "TZ=Brazil/East"
     ports:
       - "80:80"
       - "443:443"
     volumes: 
       - /www/static
     volumes_from:
       - django
     links:
       - django:django
   worker:
     build: ./django
     command: su -m worker -c "celery worker -A contactto.celeryconf -Q default -n default@%h"
     environment: 
       - "TZ=Brazil/East"
     restart: always
     volumes:
       - ./django:/usr/src/app
       - ./django/static:/usr/src/app/contactto/static
       - ./logs:/logs/
       - /asterisk/:/etc/asterisk/
     links:
       - rabbitmq:rabbitmq

 volumes: 
   dbdata:
```

My dev.yml is this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.5
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: my_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_password
      POSTGRES_DB: my_db
    volumes:
      - /psqldata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  django:
    environment:
      - "DJANGO_CONFIG_MODE=Development"
    depends_on:
      - db
  worker:
    environment:
      - "DJANGO_CONFIG_MODE=Development"
    links:
      - db:db
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please post the docker-compose.yml you're using.

Comment: Ok, I inserted this file now.

Comment: I am trying this method with mysql and continue to get `db_1            | chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/': Operation not permitted
`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I entered at `/` and stay analyzing the folders. Than I set the command `ls -la` there and I saw that the folder was with `root` user. First I deleted the folder `sudo rm -rf psqldata` and after I setted permission `sudo chmod 777 /` to create the folder with my user `mkdir psqldata` and now it is working. I don't know why before it was working and suddenly it stoped. I hope this answer can help you too.

old folder `ls -la`
`drwxr-xr-x    2 root      wheel     68 Jun 19 14:58 psqldata`

new folder `ls -la`
`drwxr-xr-x    2 gtmiyabe  wheel     68 Jun 20 10:07 psqldata`

Comment: `sudo chmod 777 /`??? If I understood correctly, you have just opened up your ENTIRE SYSTEM to anyone do whatever they want!

Comment: anyone with access to the system*

Comment: this should definitely *not* be the accepted answer...

Answer (score 1):

Use a named volume instead of bind volume

Based on this answer, which helped me:
https://superuser.com/a/1781335

Notice no slashes on the left hand side:

- pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
volumes:
  pg-data:
```